# How to create a hashmap for a specific object

Tags: java, hashmap

EDIT:
@Oscar Lopez

I have added the code you specified, and now have the following:
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

```
public class Character{
    public String name;

    private HashMap<String, String> stats;

    public Character(String charName){
        name = charName;

        stats.put("Strength", "5");
        stats.put("Dexterity", "5");
        stats.put("Constitution", "5");
        stats.put("Intelligence", "5");
        stats.put("Strength", "5");
        stats.put("Wisdom", "5");
    }

    public String getStat(String name) {
        return stats.get(name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        Character tanis = new Character("Tanis");
        System.out.println(tanis.getStat("Dexterity"));             
    }
}
```

And it seems to be compiling correctly, but it doesn't like the way I am trying to `stats.put` things into the hashmap, how  should I go about doing this?

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Character{
    public String name;


    private static HashMap<String, String> stats;

    public Character(String charName){
        name = charName;
        stats = new HashMap<String, String>();
        stats.put("Strength", "5");
        stats.put("Dexterity", "5");
        stats.put("Constitution", "5");
        stats.put("Intelligence", "5");
        stats.put("Strength", "5");
        stats.put("Wisdom", "5");
    }

    public String getStat(String statName) {
        return stats.get(statName);
    }

    public static void changeStat(Character character, String statName, String newStatValue) {
        character.stats.put(statName, newStatValue);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        Character tanis = new Character("Tanis");
        System.out.println(tanis.getStat("Dexterity"));

        Character xander = new Character("Xander");
        changeStat(xander, "Dexterity", "7");
        System.out.println(xander.getStat("Dexterity"));    
        System.out.println(tanis.getStat("Dexterity"));                 
    }
}

//Prints out
//5
//7
//7
```

Why is tanis.getStat changing to 7?

Comment: BTW Someone just asked for reason using a Map like this is a bad idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159502/is-there-anything-wrong-with-replacing-class-attributes-with-a-hashmap You might like to read this first.

Comment: first, next time please don't change your question totally.  For people that see your question late is going to be confusion: all answers seems not answering the question.  Either append to your question, or create a separate question if what you are asking is no longer the same.  Go back to your question: What is the problem you found using `stats.put()` that makes you dislike that?  Raise your question clearly please

Comment: You have not instantiated the HashMap object,  before start adding Key-value pairs. You should declare the tenis reference of type Map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the `HashMap` as an attribute in the `Character` class, then you can access it like you intend:

```
public class Character {
    private HashMap<String, String> stats;
    public String getStat(String name) {
        return stats.get(name);
    }
}

// elsewhere
Character tanis = new Character("Tanis");
System.out.println(tanis.getStat("Dexterity"));
```

Comment: Edited the post, please reply because you seem like someone who knows what to do.

Comment: You forgot to instantiate the map in the constructor: `stats = new HashMap<String, String>();`

Comment: Thank you sir, as you are a life saver. This is pretty much the basis for my entire program, and the hashMap just took like 400 lines of code out of the original program. I'm not really a hashMap expert, obviously, but can I have the second variable in the hashmap be an int variable as opposed to String? Because whenever I try to change it, it comes up with an error.

Comment: Nope, all of the values must be of the same type, in this case, `String`. Although you could save a number like this: `"5"` and then convert it to a real number using `Integer.parseInt()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, you were very helpful. I have one last question though... How do I go about changing values of given HashMap values? Like if I wanted to change the Dexterity value 5 to 6, how would I do that?

Comment: Create a new method called `setStat` that receives the name of the attribute (ex: "Dexterity") and the new value (ex: "5") - both are strings, and use `put()` on the map to change the value

Comment: Ok, when I change a stat, it changes all the stats. Is there a way for me to reference a characters stats hashmap? Or is the hashmap for all players? And is there a way make it so that there is a different hashmap per character?

Comment: the map is different for each character, as long as you instantiate different `Character` objects for each character (you know, `new Character(...)`

Comment: Yes, I created a new Character. But for example I have 
`Character tanis = new Character("Tanis");` and
`Character xander = new Character("Xander");` and if I change `xander.stats` by `xander.remove` the original stat and `xander.put` the new stat, if I get the stat, it changes for both xander and tanis look at the code I have in the main question.

Comment: @user2495441 Your stats variable is `static`, thus it will be the same thing for all `Character` objects. In other words, changing `stats` for one `Character` changes it for all `Characters`. Remove the `static` keyword and it should fix this. Also, you should be able to have a `HashMap<String,int>`. I'm fairly certain it doesn't need to be a `HashMap<String,String>` so that you don't have to parse the int every time

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do, but I believe the best solution is to make a `HashMap` that is a member of your `Character` class. Thus, instead of `String mapName`, you could have `HashMap<String, String> stats` or something like that. Then, to access the map for `tanis`, you would say `tanis.stats`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized the map - it is still null when you attempt to populate it.

Initialize it like this:

```
private Map<String, String> stats = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

With this change, your code will be OK.

---

Note how I have declared the map to be the *abstract* type `Map`, not the concrete implementation `HashMap`, in line with good programming practice.